# Parsing object to string in firebase

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an app where a list of objects is retrieved from a JSON Array and shown in a list view adapter. The parsing is done correctly and the list of objects are shown without any quotes. Now, i want that when the user clicks on a particular item from the list view it is added to firebase as it is shown in the list view and not include the object quotes. I am currently inserting into firebase via this:

```
String Country =(lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
showPopUp(Country);



public void showPopUp(final String country) {

    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.countryListLayout));
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.Add:


                    // Write a message to the database
                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Country Name").push();
                    myRef.setValue(country);

                    return true;
```

The result in firebase is as follows: https://gyazo.com/14aad7aa7d66a757b8da22401b88ecb5

How come the data was parsed correctly and shown how it should in the list view and then when it comes to inserting by list view item clicked it returns as object and not how it is shown exactly in the list view? Thanks